# How to submit a form using vue.js 2?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

My view blade laravel like this :

```
<form slot="search" class="navbar-search" action="{{url('search')}}">
    <search-header-view></search-header-view>
</form>
```

The view blade laravel call vue component (search-header-view component)

My vue component(search-header-view component) like this :

```
<template>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="q" autofocus v-model="keyword">
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" id="submit-search"><span class="fa fa-search"></span></button>
            </span>
            <ul v-if="!selected && keyword">
                <li v-for="state in filteredStates" @click="select(state.name)">{{ state.name }}</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        name: 'SearchHeaderView',
        data() {
            return {
                baseUrl: window.Laravel.baseUrl,
                keyword: null,
                selected: null,
                filteredStates: []
            }
        },
        watch: {
            keyword(value) {
                this.$store.dispatch('getProducts', { q: value })
                .then(res => {
                    this.filteredStates = res.data;        
                })
            }
        },
        methods: {
            select: function(state) {
                this.keyword = state
                this.selected = state
                document.getElementById('submit-search').submit()
            },
            input: function() {
                this.selected = null
            }
        },    
    }
</script>
```

I want to submit the form when user click the keyword

I try document.getElementById('submit-search').submit()

But on the console exist error like this :

> TypeError: document.getElementById(...).submit is not a function

How can I solve this error?

Comment: Have you tried the event listener that vue provided `@submit`? instead of `:action` ?

Comment: @John Rey M. Baylen, I update my question. So tag form out of component

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call `submit()` on the `<form>` element (which is the root element of the component):

```
this.$el.submit();
```

---

EDIT: Since you have updated your question, the above no longer applies.

To trigger a button click, just call `click()` on the button element:

```html
<button ref="submitButton">Foo</button>
```

```js
this.$refs.submitButton.click();
```

This is fine if your components are meant to be tightly-coupled, otherwise a cleaner solution would be to `$emit` an event from your `<search-header-view>` component and respond to it in the parent component, like this:

```js
this.$emit('submit');
```

In parent component:

```html
<search-header-view @submit="submit">
```

```js
methods: {
  submit() {
    // Submit the form manually here (add a ref to your form element)
    this.$refs.form.submit();
  }
}
```

Comment: It does not work. There exist error : `TypeError: this.$el.submit is not a function`

Comment: I need you help again. Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47879651/how-can-i-update-value-in-input-type-text-on-vue-js-2

Answer (score 1):

Just provide the `@submit` listener to your form :

```
<form slot="search" class="navbar-search" @submit="submited">
  <search-header-view></search-header-view>
</form>
```

And the associated method :

```
methods: {
  submited (e) {
    // e is the form event, e.target is the form, do your things on submit
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the case where it says that `submit is not a function` even though you reference it correclt with `$refs`:
It looks like if a form control has a name or id of submit it will mask the form's submit method.
In my case I had `name="submit"` on my submit button, I removed it and it worked fine.